# Does D automatically rewrite opBinary to opOpAssign?

Tags: operator-overloading, d

for example, assuming that T implements the right operator overloads:

```
T t1, t2, t3;
t3 = t1 + t2; // t3.opAssign(t1.opBinary!"+"(t2)) for sure
t3 = t3 + t2; // rewritten to t3.opOpAssign!"+"(t2) ?
```

Is the last operation optimized by D ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. It is not possible, because `opBinary` and `opOpAssign` could have different semantic:

```
struct S
{
    int val = 5;

    S opBinary(string op)(S rhs) if (op == "+")
    {
        return S(val + rhs.val);
    }

    void opOpAssign(string op)(S rhs) if (op == "+")
    {
        val = val - rhs.val;
    }
}

void main()
{
    import std.stdio;

    S s1, s2, s3;
    writeln(s3); // S(5)

    s3 = s3 + s2;
    writeln(s3); // S(10)

    s3.val = 5;
    writeln(s3); // S(5)

    s3 += s2;
    writeln(s3); // S(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `opOpBinary`? Did you mean `opOpAssign`?

And no, it doesn't. For example, appending (`~=`) and concatenating (`~`) arrays are different operations (the former preallocates extra space at the end and the latter will always reallocate).

Comment: in the last example it's the same: `t3 = t3 + t2` and `t3 += t2`. I don't  know why is come with the cat operator.

Comment: What was motivation for down-voting this answer?

Comment: it was an error.Tried to reset to 0 later but it didn't work. nvm, nothing personal.